# Warning on multiple assignment

Tags: scala

Suppose I have

```
def f() = (1, 2, 3)
```

Somewhere in code I call it:

```
val (a, b, c) = f()
```

But this can easily be confused with multiple assignments:

```
val a, b, c = f() // here every variable == (1, 2, 3)
```

Moreover, I have never used this multiple assignments feature. For the reasons above I think it's harmful. Is it possible to make compiler warn on it?

Comment: How is it "harmful"? Surely, the error will become evident on the few next lines, where you try to use the variable you just declared ...

Comment: It may become, and may not. I don't want to give a chance for typos.

Comment: How can it "not"? You can, probably, come up with some really obscure case where it doesn't (I can't really think of any off the top of my head), but my response to that would be that avoiding obscure cases is what you should use to not "give a chance for typos to begin with".

Comment: For example, if the function that works with 'a, b, c' accepts both tuples and single variables (e.g. is overloaded), and the logic is different. Use your imagination :)

Comment: You mean `def foo(x: Any)`? Well ... don't write functions like that. This is not perl. Seriously, you are misplacing the blame here: it is having a function that "accepts both tuples and single variables" that is "harmful" in this case, not the multiple assignment thingy.

Comment: For example, it may write a json. And that json will be sent to some third-party api. That could be caught by tests, but, as I said, I want to reduce a changes to make dumb mistakes. I can imagine several more cases easily (logging, serialization, actor messaging, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is currently no. That said, if you want to build a compiler plugin to do just this, then you can achieve this goal of issuing a warning. That said, how to build a compiler plugin is beyond the scope of an answer here.

Comment: There is bunch of "-Ywarn*" compiler flags. Where are they implemented?